# sqlalchemy polymorhic_identity not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use polymorphic_on on a python class with several inheritances:

```
engine = create_engine(
    'mysql://xxx:yyy@localhost:3306/zzz?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0',
    pool_recycle=3600, echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

class AbstractPersistent(object):
    version = Column('VERSION', Integer)
    last_modified_by = Column('LAST_MODIFIED_BY', String(255))
    last_modified_date = Column('LAST_MODIFIED_DATE', Date)
    created_by = Column('CREATED_BY', String(255))
    created_date = Column('CREATED_DATE', Date)

class AbstractNamed(AbstractPersistent):
    eid = Column('ENTERPRISE_ID', String(255))
    title = Column('TITLE', String(255))
    description = Column('DESCRIPTION', String(255))

class AbstractContainer(AbstractNamed):
    __tablename__ = 'CM_MEMBER_CONTAINER_T'    
    id = Column('MEMBER_CONTAINER_ID',Integer,primary_key=True)
    discriminator = Column('CLASS_DISCR', String(100))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator }

class CourseSet(Base,AbstractContainer):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.impl.CourseSetCmImpl'}
```

As you can see, `CourseSet` contains all the columns of its parents and has the column `CLASS_DISCR`  sets to `'org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.impl.CourseSetCmImpl'`.

But when it make a query fro all `CourseSet`:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
course_sets = session.query(CourseSet).all()
print(course_sets)
```

It returns all the entries of `'CM_MEMBER_CONTAINER_T'`, but I want only the ones with `CLASS_DISCR` set to `'org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.impl.CourseSetCmImpl'`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Michael on the google group sqlalchemy](http://groups.google.fr/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/1ef3f726670b5000), this is the answer:

> `AbstractContainer` is not mapped, its a mixin, so its `__mapper_args__` are not
>   used until a subclass of `Base` is invoked, which starts up a declarative
>   mapping.  Your only mapped class then is `CourseSet`, which has its own
>   `__mapper_args__` , that override those of `AbstractContainer` - they are
>   ignored.
>
> To combine `__mapper_args__` from a mapped class with those of a
>   mixin, see the example at
>   http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html?highlight=declarative#combining-table-mapper-arguments-from-multiple-mixins 
>   It uses `__table_args__` but the same concept of creating a full dictionary
>   of arguments applies for `__mapper_args__` as well.